# jQuery.validate only triggers on submit in my Rails App

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I'm trying to integrate the jQuery Validate plugin into my Rails app:

```
<script>
$(function() {
      $("#edit_researcher").validate({
        debug: false,
        rules: {
          "researcher[first_name]": {required: true},
          "researcher[email]": {required: true, email: true}
        },
        messages: {
          "researcher[first_name]": { required: "First name is required" },
          "researcher[email]": {
          required: "Email is required",
          email: "Your email address must be in the format of name@domain.com"
          }
        }
    });
</script>
```

This is working, but the problem is that the `.validate` method is only triggered when the submit button is clicked. I would like to have it triggered at `onfocus` and `onblur`, as I believe is the default for `jQuery.validate()`.

Does anyone encountered the same issue when implement `jQuery.validate()` in a Rails app?

How can I make it trigger the validation on `onfocus` and `onblur`?

Comment: There is nothing you've shown us in your code above that would be breaking the default behavior of the plugin.  Where is your HTML markup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Quote OP**:

> *"... the problem is that the `.validate` method is only triggered when the submit button is clicked. I would like to have it triggered at `onfocus` and `onblur`, as I believe is the default for `jQuery.validate()`."*

There are no such events in this plugin as `onfocus` and `onblur`.  Actually, the default behaviors are `onfocusout` and `onkeyup`.  HOWEVER, these two behaviors only start working *after* an initial click of the submit button.

Your existing code:  http://jsfiddle.net/bu7ukmvy/

This default behavior is called "Lazy Validation" as opposed to "Eager Validation", which is what you seem to be requesting.

You can modify the `onfocusout` and `onkeyup` callback functions to ignore if the user already clicked the submit button and instead have them get triggered upon the first blur and key-up.

```
$("#edit_researcher").validate({
    // rules & options,
    ....,
    onfocusout: function (element) {
        this.element(element);
    },
    onkeyup: function (element, event) {
        this.element(element);
    }
});
```

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/bu7ukmvy/1/**

Comment: hi Sparky, thanks a lot, I added your code and it is working now : )

Comment: @Toontje, you're welcome.  You wanted "eager" validation, where "lazy" validation is this plugin's default.  See my edits.